# error CS0535 Class does not implement interface member Blazor

Tags: c#, interface, blazor-server-side

I have this class and this interface. It throws the error CS0535: 'CustomerService' does not implement interface member 'ICustomerService.Uid'.

I do not understand why I am getting this error.

```
public class CustomerService : ICustomerService 

{ 
       public string Uid { get; set;}
        {
            Uid = Guid.NewGuid().ToString();
         }
}

public interface ICustomerService
    {
        string Uid { get; set;}
     
    }



Startup.cs

services.AddTransient<ICustomerService, CustomerService>();
```

Comment: Do you want to get the same Id over and over again or do you want a newly genereted Id on every property access?

Answer (score 3):

Normally, your code *shouldn't* compile. You should get an error like:

> Cannot access non-static property 'Uid' in static context

If you want to initialize `Uid`, you could try this:

```
public class CustomerService : ICustomerService
{
    public string Uid { get; set; } = Guid.NewGuid().ToString();
}
```